# Selecting clusters based on number of nodes iGraph/R

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory, sna

Is there a way to select a subgraph/subset where clusters have maximum number of vertices?

Essentially I want to do something like:

```
want <- components(X)$csize < 20
```

I thought about merging the cluster id's from the graph data frame to the node df, then using a count, or something similar, to subset the original df and compute the graph data frame again.

Comment: Right now I can only answer with "yes". An answer to the obvious follow-up question "how?" requires a reproducible example. I would appreciate if you could provide one. Please refer to this FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other than the fact that the function is named `components` (not `component`) your line of code should work fine.  What do you need that your code is not already doing?

Comment: The above code returns a logical. I figured it out I think: X[X$csize < 20]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution using a random graph. You will need to use `groups` on the `components` to identify which **nodes** belong to which **components**, then you will need to use `length` to identify how big the components are:

```
set.seed(4321)
g <- sample_gnm(100, 40, F, F)
plot(g, vertex.size = 5, vertex.label = '')
```

[image: The entire graph with all components]

```
want <- g %>%
  components %>%
  groups %>%
  .[sapply(., length) > 3]
```

`want` will provide the following:

```
$`1`
[1]  1 34 38 45 75

$`3`
 [1]   3  12  24  39  50  54  58  60  67  84  97  99 100

$`5`
[1]  5 35 37 41 44 53 65 90
```

Then you can remove all nodes that aren't included in `want`

```
newG <- g %>%
  {. - V(.)[! as.numeric(V(.)) %in% unlist(want)]}

plot(newG, vertex.size = 5, vertex.label = '')
```

[image]